# Rendering a PNG/Leer

Tags: rendering, settings

I simply copied a PNG picture in my scene, but when i hit render, it wont show up. I checked the render-settings but couldn't find anything.

Comment: pls provide your blend file. open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Ql5x1Wz6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Ql5x1Wz6/)

Comment: You need to pack your image into the Blend file (File > External Data > Pack resources) and upload it again so that we can see it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=AjoKBoKl" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/AjoKBoKl/)

Comment: and please watch some free beginner tutorials: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/ they are really helpful and free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag'n drop an image into Blender, it is a so called "Image as reference" and won't be rendered. They just show up in the viewport. So if you want to render them, use image as planes or a plane with an image shader.

So do this:

Shift-A  -> Mesh -> Plane

Go in shading tab, press New

press Shift-A (in shading, not in the viewport),

[image]

Texture -> image texture

connect it like this:

[image]

click on open and choose your image file.

[image]

Comment: I want to see "Leer" in my rendered image...

Comment: got that, i update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: you are welcome!